# prettyPhoto with valid W3C but no Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, prettyphoto

I'm using the current code in the header to make prettyPhoto valid by W3C.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
     social_tools:false 
     });
 });
```

Untouched Code and Recommended by prettyPhoto Documentation

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
</script>
```

With the on page code as follows.

```
<li><a href="http://cdn.domain.com/1.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img class="lazy" src="http://cdn.domain.com/grey.gif" data-original="http://cdn.domain.com/1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
<li><a href="http://cdn.domain.com/2.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img class="lazy" src="http://cdn.domain.com/grey.gif" data-original="http://cdn.domain.com/2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
```

PS. It's using LazyLoad on the thumb, but thats working fine too.

The images are **WORKING** in the lightbox by prettyPhoto but they are not opening in Gallery (no next, prev etc, I think its not detecting the other images using the same tag), I suspect it has to do with the [pp_gal] and the code that I've written to get it working on data-gal instead of rel=.

I suspect this is a easy fix for the jQuery Gurus. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of your data attraibutes is `prettyPhoto[pp_gal]` and not plain `prettyPhoto` we can infer that the `prettyPhoto` plug-in looks there to get the information it needs to do what you want.

You need to go into the source of `prettyPhoto` and make it look at `data-gal` instead of `rel`.

Comment: Is there no way to Rewrite (Override the REL with additional Script)

Comment: $('a[data-rel]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('rel', $(this).data('rel'));
}); would something like this work?

Comment: What's the point of making the raw HTML valid if you use JavaScript to invalidate the generated DOM?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating it seems that prettyPhoto have improved their code recently and adopting this change was straight forward since they now Hook the 'REL' attribute and changing one value fixes all. Whoop Whoop!

Believe is an example of how to make prettyPhoto W3C Valid. 
Online 8 you have this

```
(function($){$.prettyPhoto={version:'3.1.4'};$.fn.prettyPhoto=function(pp_settings){pp_settings=jQuery.extend({hook:'data-gal',animation_speed:'fast',ajaxcallback:function(){},slideshow:5000,autoplay_slideshow:false,opacity:0.80,show_title:true,allow_resize:true,allow_expand:true,default_width:500,default_height:344,counter_separator_label:'/',theme:'pp_default',horizontal_padding:20,hideflash:false,wmode:'opaque',autoplay:true,modal:false,deeplinking:true,overlay_gallery:true,overlay_gallery_max:30,keyboard_shortcuts:true,changepicturecallback:function(){},callback:function(){},ie6_fallback:true,markup:'<div class="pp_pic_holder">
```

Look For this

```
jQuery.extend({hook:'rel'
```

And change to

```
jQuery.extend({hook:'data-gal'
```

Alternatively you can download the version that I edited, its the latest version and be found here [jquery.prettyPhoto-3.1.4-W3C.js](http://www.bybe.net/downloads/jquery.prettyPhoto-3.1.4-W3C.js)